# Hide status messages generated from Commerce - Not required with use of Ajax add to cart module

Tags: commerce, status-messages

I am using a nice little module [Commerce Ajax Cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_ajax_cart) which adds products to the cart without a refresh.

However, my only little issue is that when then navigating to the checkout page, it displays all the status messages for the products that have been added to cart.

I could hide these with CSS using the status class, however, this could also hide any important status messages with it.

So my question is, how can I hide the status messages from commerce, or if anyone knows where these status messages are being generated from within the commerce modules.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're referencing the "Display an Add to Cart Message" Rule.  Looks like: 
[image: Display an Add To Cart Message Notification screengrab]

To disable this go to:
Configuration > Workflow > Rules > Disable - Display an Add To Cart Message.